# Is there a solution to the fact that Visual Studio 2008 flashes like crazy over RDC?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, remote-desktop

Editing with Visual Studio 2008 over Remote Desktop Connection is an insane exercise in patience, as the screen paints and repaints and repaints and flashes like crazy.

Is there any easy fix for this?

Both sides are running Windows 7. Vanilla Visual Studio, without anything installed. Literally every keystroke results in the whole window repainting itself, often multiple times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS 2008 SP1 over Remote Desktop: Constant Repainting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873849/vs-2008-sp1-over-remote-desktop-constant-repainting)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I had Remote Desktop running in 32 bit color mode. In 24 bit mode, it's much much faster.

Comment: I had better experiences when the server was Win7/Vista Enterprise/Ultimate with Aero enabled. Aero forces most of the stuff to be rendered on the client side and makes Remote Desktop feel much better.

Comment: Doesn't that also require that the RD client is running Vista/W7?

Answer (score 2):

Turning off **Resharper** fixed this problem for me. I was using a Cisco VPN from Windows XP to Windows Server 2003