# VS 2008 SP1 text editor flickering over remote desktop connection

Tags: visual-studio-2008, remote-desktop, flicker

I am connecting from a Windows 7 x64 machine to my dev machine running Windows XP SP3 using the built in remote desktop client.  For most apps it works fine with no problems, for Visual Studio whenever I am typing the entire text editor keeps redrawing.

I stumbled across this question:  [VS 2008 SP1 over Remote Desktop: Constant Repainting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873849/vs-2008-sp1-over-remote-desktop-constant-repainting) and I have tried all of the suggestions in it to no effect, including resetting all VS settings back to default then disabling the suggested settings.  Has anyone found a reliable solution to this?  I feel like I'm going insane with the screen constantly refreshing when I'm working from home.

Some additional information:
Remote Desktop is set to run at 1680x1050, 15bit color, Low-speed broadband for the experience setting with all but Visual styles and Persistent bitmap caching unchecked.

Visual Studio 2008 Team System is running on the dev machine with Service Pack 1 and Power Commands installed.

**Update:** I can connect to one of the virtual machines in the same building and use VS2008 without experiencing this issue, the VMs are running Windows 2003 Server so I don't know if that's making a difference here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning off ClearType if you're running Win7.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about this question but this was what I ended up doing and it did work so I'm marking this as the answer.  Since then the hard drive on my dev machine crashed and I was issued a new one running Windows 7 plus we've moved to VS2010 and this issue doesn't occur anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I work in a similar environment (connecting from India to a machine in US) and observed that the network speed matters. We had to sort out things related to router and all..

Comment: Well I know our connection at work is not very fast so this may be part of my problem though I asked two of my co-workers and they don't have the issue.